# Ошибка выборки из базы

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель. Я добавил в неё новое поле. Далее выполнил след. команды:

```
sudo -u owner python manage.py migrate my_app
sudo -u owner python manage.py syncdb --my_app
```

Но при выборке данных выпадает ошибка доступа к базе, выбираю несуществующее поле.

PS При синхронизации почему-то говорит, что не надо ничего синхронизировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что Джанго не позволяет изменять существующие модели. С их точки зрения надо удалить таблицу в базе и создать заново с помощью `syncdb`.

Судя по тому, что Вы пытаетесь использовать `migrate`, которого в стандартом `manage.py` нет, у Вас установлена какая-то *система миграции моделей* (неплохо было бы указать это в вопросе). Думаю, Вам следует ознакомиться с её документацией, чтобы узнать, как правильно выполнить миграцию.

---

Наиболее популярен, насколько мне известно, проект [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). Если Вы пользуетесь им, то миграция моделей осуществляется в два этапа:

1. `./manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto` (либо с другими параметрами в зависимости от ситуации).
2. `./manage.py migrate app_name`

При этом `syncdb` более ни в каких случаяx использовать не надо — South заменяет его целиком.

Comment: Да, используется South, но я выполняю миграцию, она тоже говорит, что все ок, и ничего менять не надо.

Comment: Прочитайте ещё раз мой ответ. «Если Вы пользуетесь им, то миграция моделей осуществляется в два этапа». Разница между первым и вторым существенная. Чтобы произошла миграция надо СНАЧАЛА выполнить первое, А ЗАТЕМ выполнить второе. По порядку. Не что-то одно на выбор, а сначала первое, потом второе. Иначе миграция не произойдёт. Чтоб произошла миграция, необходимо выполнить ДВЕ команды. Миграция модели не осуществляется одной командой. Миграция модели осуществляется ДВУМЯ командами. Выполненными по очереди.

Answer (score -1):

Все эти сложности... Не проще ли вручную подправить существующую базу, добавив в таблицу нужное поле?

Comment: Нет, гораздо проще набрать две команды в консоли. Особенно, если миграция заключается не только в добавлении одного поля.